# Create MVC4 Membership Database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm familiar with `aspnet_regsql.exe` to create a membership database (it produces 11 tables)

However, in my MVC4 project VS2010 created a Membership Database with just six tables (Applications, Memberships, Profiles, Roles, Users & UsersInRoles)

How can I create a database with this (new?) schema?

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a pre-MVC4 application using the new MVC4/ASP.Net 4.5 six-table DB schema?

Comment: Ok, the providers in MVC 4 are NOT the same, MVC4 introduces new providers - nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aspnet_regsql.exe` is a part of ASP.Net architecture, not MVC.

My bet is that the MVC4 Developer Preview comes with some custom schema scripts in its project structure, or that it has a preview version of the new ASP.Net 4.5 version `aspnet_regsql.exe` installed.

If the later is true, you could perhaps use that to create a database, and tie it into your MVC3 (and prior) applications. The implications here are because of the schema differences, you would likely need to write your own Providers.

Another option would be to create the database with your MVC4 template, delete the project, and code a DA layer in your MVC3 project that uses the database. All you'd need to grab is the connection string. But again, you would have to roll your own providers as the old ones wouldn't know the new 6-table schema.

Comment: Thanks one.beat but Ive been poking around and discovered the providers are in fact different in MVC4. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, ASP.Net 4.5 will have new providers and new db schema. Personally, I prefer to roll my own instead of using all their membership stuff. It's like a fatty steak sometimes. ;)

Comment: @LillyPop - did I answer your question well enough?

Comment: Yes one beat, thought id ticked it but had just voted up, tis done :-)

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is:

change your web.config to point to the connection you would like

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="uid=****;pwd=*****;server=(local);database=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Verify Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

Line 41 should read:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Notice that autoCreateTables is set to true and the name of the connection you set in the web.config is set.

**Now when a user registers it will be looking at the database you set up. If the tables don't exist yet they will be created.**

Answer (score 2):

You have to add some arguments for installing features: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

You can run Aspnet_regsql.exe without any command-line arguments to run a wizard that will walk you through the installation.

Which tables are missing and which tables was created?

Comment: Whilst this is almost the right answer(I just tried it using the command line option to only create the same six tables), VS2010 MVC4 is creating tables with a slightly different structure (eg there is no Memberships/MobilePIN in mvc db schema) So im thinking they must have created it another way??

Comment: I think you should have a look at this article: http://computerscribe.com/blogs/blogPost?id=11

Comment: Great article thanks, I understand a lot more now. I have loaded the scipts mentioned in the article (Common, Membership & Roles) into SQL Server Management Studio but the tables they produce are named aspnet_Membership, this is the problem, as the tables produced by MVC4 when you use the internet app template produce tables names Membership, Roles (without the aspnet_ part) MVC4 is doing something different...

Comment: Ok, providers are not the same, MVC4 introduces new providers -  http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers